# How to insert NULL value to UUID instead of zeros

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a table in postgres with a UUID field type that must be unique but can be null

with a table & model like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asdf(
    id bigserial primary key,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    key uuid unique,
    created_at timestamptz,
    updated_at timestamptz
);
```

and the go model defined as

```
type Asdf struct {
    ID          uint64    `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;column:id"`
    Name        string    `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Key         uuid.UUID `json:"key" gorm:"column:key"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"column:created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at"`
}
```

`result := db.Connect().Create(asdf.Asdf{ID:123,Name:"This is the name"})`

and prints the following sql query to the terminal

```
INSERT INTO "asdf" ("id","name","key","created_at","updated_at")
VALUES('123','This is the name','00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','2022-04-27 03:41:49.338','2022-04-27 03:41:49.338')
```

it inserted the model into the database with `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`as the `key` value instead of NULL

I also notice this happen with string type where it inserted an empty string `''` instead of NULL

how do i make gorm insert NULL instead of zeros/empty string as the value ?

Comment: try changing this field's type to `Key *uuid.UUID`. You would obviously have to adapt your go code too.

Comment: I think gorm also honors the regular `sql` interfaces, so you may also try to define a custom type which implements [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) (to turn `null` to `""` on sql -> go conversion) and [`driver.Valuer`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Valuer) (from the `sql/driver` package, to turn `""` to `null` on go -> sql conversion). I haven't tested it though, so you would have to try it yourself.

Comment: I've added the asterisk to the type, it fixed the problem

I also tried this to the string type and worked too @LeGEC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your field's type to a pointer type :

```
type Asdf struct {
    ID          uint64     `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;column:id"`
    Name        string     `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    Key         *uuid.UUID `json:"key" gorm:"column:key"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `json:"created_at" gorm:"column:created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time  `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at"`
}
```

You would obviously have to adapt your go code too (e.g: check if `record.Key != nil`, access `*record.Key` instead of `record.Key`, etc ...)

---

I think gorm also honors the regular sql interfaces, so you may also try to define a custom type which implements :

- [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Scanner) to turn `null` into `""` on sql -> go conversions,
- [`driver.Valuer`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver#Valuer) (from the `sql/driver` package) to turn `""` to `null` on go -> sql conversions.

I haven't tested it though, so you would have to try it yourself.

Comment: Implementing `Scanner` and `Valuer` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are using is not specified in the question. If you are using [satori/go.uuid](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/satori/go.uuid), you can use the [NullUUID type](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/satori/go.uuid#NullUUID):

```
type Asdf struct {
    ID          uint64         `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;column:id"`
    Name        string         `json:"name" gorm:"column:name"`
    NullableKey uuid.NullUUID `json:"key" gorm:"column:key"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time      `json:"created_at" gorm:"column:created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time      `json:"updated_at" gorm:"column:updated_at"`
}
```

To set a value:

```
key := uuid.NullUUID{
    Value: id,  // of type uuid.UUID
    Valid: true
}
```

To save null, just save the zero value. Both `Scan` & `Value` methods are already defined.